# Setting a relation without fetching the object with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dto

I have two entity classes: `Person` and `Position`.

```
public class Person
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Code { get; set; }
}
```

`Person` has a one-to-many relationship with `Position`. I also have a DTO `PersonDto` that brings the person data from the client.

```
public class PersonDto
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int PositionId { get; set; }
}
```

After I get the DTO I have to create a new `Person` object and persist it. Usually it looks like this:

```
var person = new Person();
CopyFromDto(person, personDto);
var position = positionRepository.GetById(personDto.PositionId);
person.Position = position;
personRepository.Save(person);
```

I wonder if I could get rid of this line:

```
var position = positionRepository.GetById(personDto.PositionId);
```

The reason is that it produces an unneccessary SQL query that fetches some position data. Is it possible to somehow provide NHibernate with the position id and save a person row with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ISession.Load`:

> The Load() methods of ISession give you a way to retrieve a persistent
>   instance if you already know its identifier.
>
> Note that Load() will throw an unrecoverable exception if there is no
>   matching database row. If the class is mapped with a proxy, Load()
>   returns an object that is an uninitialized proxy and does not actually
>   hit the database until you invoke a method of the object. This
>   behaviour is very useful if you wish to create an association to an
>   object without actually loading it from the database.

https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-loading